# Where private attributes of base class in object of child class?

Tags: c++

I am learning Object-Oriented Programming by using C++. I have tried to write following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
private:
  int att_1;
  int att_2;
  int att_3;
public:
  A()
  {
    att_1 = att_2 = att_3 = 0; 
  }
  int sum()
  {
    return att_1+att_2 + att_3;
  }
};
//Class B want to inherits from class A
//Class B also has doSomeThing() method that is not related to A attributes
class B : public A
{
public:
//just a function to show something
  void doSomeThing()
  {
    cout << "I am B object\n";
  }
};
//class C just want to inherits doSomeThing() method from B
//and it also has an attribute that named as d
class C :public B
{
public:
  int att_4;
};
int main()
{
  C obj;
  obj.doSomeThing();
  cout<<sizeof(C); //sizeof(C)=20 bytes
             //sizeof(C)=20 bytes, it includes att_1, att_2, att_3 and att_4
             //but "obj" does not want to use att_1, att_2, att_3
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see,"obj" just want to inherits doSomeThing() method from class B and it does not want to use att_1, att_2, att_3 but it must spend
space to store class A attributes( att_1, att_2, att_3). It wastes memory. I want to ask, are we forced to accept this prodigality?

Comment: Yes, if you inherit from `B` you get `B`'s `A` part with it as it is part of what makes `B` a `B`.

Comment: Thank for your comment. It really wastes memory, so we should design good classes to limit that.

Comment: `obj` doesn't want to use attr_1-4, but it *can*: `int s = obj.sum();` That is the basic principle of object oriented programming and inheritance